# Closest span element selector - styled components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to get Styled Components to work with selecting the closest *span* element

```
<label>
   <span className="">Password</span>
   <input type="password" id="passwordInput" />
</label>
```

```
     span {
          position: absolute;
          font-size: 14px;
          height: 40px;
          color: #a2a2a2;
          line-height: 40px;
          right: 0;
          left: 8px;
          cursor: auto;
        }
        input {
          height: 40px;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          width: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
          background-color: #fafafa;
          border-radius: 3px;
          cursor: auto;
          font-size: 16px;

          &:focus {
            & + span {
              background-color: red;
            }
            outline: #a2a2a2;
            border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
          }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to go about it, this is what I'm trying right now and it's not working. Preferably I would like to have them work without giving the span, specific classes.

Comment: You can't with CSS. You cannot select a preceding sibling. You can change your markup to put the span AFTER the input element and then use CSS to move them into the position you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed using the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), but it only applies to selectors following the selector on the left -

> The **adjacent sibling combinator** (`+`) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it *immediately* follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

This means that if you were to put the `input` tag first, then it would work. Unfortunately, there's no such thing as a 'previous sibling' yet, so your best choice would be to think of another way to structure your markup and/or CSS.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that have an already marked duplicate.